# The window.ui with form conveted converted to window.py error in PySide2.QtWidgets.QTabWidget(MyWindow)

Tags: python, pyside2

I create a window

[image: CREATE USERS]

and in the Python code I did:

```
def __init__(self):
    try:
        super(QDialog, self).__init__()
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = uic.loadUi('CreateUsers.ui', self)
```

You can show that I used "CreateUsers.ui" file, but I used pyside2-uic CreateUsers.ui > ui_create_user.py  and tried to use with this way:

```
def __init__(self):
    try:
        super(QDialog, self).__init__()
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        #self.ui = uic.loadUi('CreateUsers.ui', self)
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
```

I converted this all in EXE used pyinstaller, but when I try to use appear a error in PySide2 with these messages:

```
FIXME Subscripted generics cannot be used with class and instance checks
Erro na tela inicial: 'PySide2.QtWidgets.QTabWidget' called with wrong argument types:
  PySide2.QtWidgets.QTabWidget(MyWindow)
Supported signatures:
  PySide2.QtWidgets.QTabWidget(typing.Union[PySide2.QtWidgets.QWidget, NoneType] = None)
```

The window appeared empty too

[image: Empty Window here]

This application I created in python to manage SAP users create. This application load all sap users, load from ProcessMaker a list of users that will be create and we use this tool(AutoSAP) to with one button and others to check if ok, we create users in SAP.

Please, somebody has an idea with I solve this issue?

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

**CreateUsers.ui** is missing on pyinstaller bundled binaries. pass CreateUsers.ui in **datas** argment or use a spec file as above to provide missing **CreateUsers.ui**

> before trying the pyinstaller again you may copy CreateUsers.ui to
>   pyinstaller output folder to test

```
block_cipher = None
a = Analysis(['minimal.py'],
     pathex=['/Developer/PItests/minimal'],
     binaries=None,
     datas=None,
     hiddenimports=[],
     hookspath=None,
     runtime_hooks=None,
     excludes=None,
     cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
     cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,... )
coll = COLLECT(...)
```

> datas: non-binary files included in the app, including names given by
>   the --add-data option.

[pyinstaller reference](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html)

Comment: Thanks Oetzi.
I adjust block try except in each method and function and I discovered that I needed to put .ui.Field in each items in window. So I did this and work well now.
Other thing I did convertion with PyQT5 tool and no more with Pyside2.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: you are welcome. PySide2 would be sustainable in longterm hence Qt Company owns it.